# svnnotify with websvn

Tags: svn, websvn

I have configured svnnotify to send email after every commit. Now I want to directly provide the URL in the modified paths field of the mail to show diff via websvn, i.e., all the modified files should be directly open through websvn along with difference between previous and present version.

Please find below the requirements,
My current post-commit hook script is,

```
#!/bin/sh

 REPOS="$1"
 REV="$2"


   /usr/local/bin/svnnotify --repos-path "$1" --revision "$2" \
   --to srikanth@mydomain.com\
   --from commitnotifier@mydomain.com \
   --svnweb-url 'http://<svnip>/websvn/revision.php?repname=repos+1&isdir=1&'
   --subject-cx \
   --subject-prefix 'REPO-NAME ' \
```

Output of the above script is:

```
Revision: 37
         http://<svnip>/websvn/revision.php?repname=repos+1&isdir=1&/revision/?rev=37&view=rev
Author:   srikanth
Date:     2011-12-28 13:08:33 +0530 (Wed, 28 Dec 2011)
Log Message:
-----------
Testing for multiple locations checkin

Modified Paths:
--------------
   trunk/branch1/test1.java
   trunk/branch2/test2.java
```

I want to modify the above script in such a way that whenever the user clicks on modified paths it should display difference directly in websvn. Request your suggestions on this.

Thank you,
srikanth B

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing variables (placed into {} brackets) in following urls to make it suitable for your specific case:

```
http://{websvn_url}/diff.php?repname={reponame}&path={file_to_compare}&rev=PREV
```

for single file comparison

```
http://{websvn_url}/comp.php?repname={reponame}&compare[]={folder_to_compare}@$2&compare[]={folder_to_compare}@HEAD
```

for folder comparison

Maybe that will not work, but at least will give you a hint to find proper solution.